# How can I update the kernel in WSL2 kernel to latest release?

Tags: linux, kernel, wsl2

The current kernel version in my WSL2 subsystem is:

```
5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

However, I see in [the official Microsoft WSL GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel/releases) there is a newer version of the kernel:

```
linux-msft-wsl-5.10.102.1
```

How can I update the kernel in my already installed WSL setup? I tried this:

```
wsl --update
```

But it does not update the kernel version.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running.  Be specific with the exact build number.  If you are not running the current Insider Preview build for WIndows 11 you will likely have to build the kernel yourself and use a custom configuration file to use it.  You can also just wait until the appropriate release of Windows includes the kernel update.

Comment: Edition Windows 10 Enterprise

Version 21H2

Installed on ‎03/‎12/‎2021
OS build 19044.1586
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To be sure of getting updates to the WSL2 kernel:

- Windows 10 : Open
  *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update*.
  Windows 11 : Open *Settings > Windows Update*.
- Click on "Advanced options"
- Enable "Receive updates for other Microsoft products when you update Windows"
- Returning to the previous page in Settings, click "Check for updates".

This will allow Windows to install the latest Linux 2 kernel for WSL 2.

The presence of a later version on Github does not mean that it was yet
incorporated into the Stable version.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - It's a perfectly correct answer.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - If you must know, I actually consider it incomplete, compared to your answer

Comment: Small corrections; it's called "Update & Security"

Answer (score 44):

There are currently at least three ways to upgrade your WSL2 kernel:

1. For recent Windows versions (Windows 10 21H2 and Windows 11), `wsl --update` is typically the best option, but realize that there is a slight lag between the time that Microsoft releases a kernel on Github and the time that they make it available for automatic updates.

   When this question was written:

   - 5.10.60.1 was the most recent available release for automatic update on Windows 11
   - 5.10.16 was the latest for Windows 10.
   - 5.10.102.1 was the latest available in the Github repository for the WSL2 kernel.  It had just been released a few days earlier on March 8th.  This is why `wsl --update` wasn't pulling it in (at the time) for the OP -- It was simply not yet available for `wsl --update` (or Windows automatic updates either).

   However, now, as of the time of this edit:

   - 5.10.102.1 is the latest *stable* kernel available via `wsl --update` (and automatic Windows updates) for both Windows 10 and 11 systems.
   - 5.15.57.1 has just been made available as the latest Preview release (on Windows 11 Insider builds).

   Note that you may need to run `wsl --update` in an Administrative session to update.

   If needed, you can revert to the previous kernel release with:

   ```
   wsl --update --rollback
   ```

   Regardless, I recommend renaming (or moving to another location) the previous kernel before updating, so that you can toggle between various kernels if needed using the `.wslconfig` file.

   Note:  There is also currently a "Preview" release of WSL available in the Microsoft Store for Windows 11 users.  If you are using this Store version, then `wsl --update` will not only update the kernel itself, but also the WSL Store package with the latest version.  Because it is a user-level application, you no longer need to run `wsl --update` in an Administrative session.  `wsl --update --rollback` is also *no longer available* in these releases.
2. For older versions of Windows 10 that don't support `wsl --update`, please see [@harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1709473/1210833).  You can still opt in to automatic updates, and (when available) the new kernel will be upgraded via the normal Windows Update mechanism.
3. Finally, you can certainly compile your own WSL2 kernel.  It's best to start from the Microsoft sources, since it has the right selection of config options for the kernel to best operate in Windows/WSL2.

   Once you've compiled or obtained a custom kernel, you can specify it be used for all WSL2 instances by creating a [`.wslconfig`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#wslconfig) with the [appropriate section and kernel config](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configuration-setting-for-wslconfig).

Comment: i already run

wsl --update

and the kernel version keeps the same.
I thought it was an error, because there was a newer version in the WSL Github rerpo.

It means, the latest version in the repo is not necessarily the latest released to current Windows installations ?

Comment: @sjrm That's correct.  Those "released" on Github aren't necessarily always pulled into WSL2 automatically.  That's a fairly recent change, I believe.  It looks like they are making more "incremental" changes in the repo, and only releasing to mainstream when there's a major new feature like USB/IP.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the version of the WSL2 can and often is dependent on the Windows 10 version, so not all WSL kernel versions, will be released to Windows 10.

Answer (score 19):

For those, who can't update WSL kernel with `wsl --update` due to strict user update policy in their company, they can install a WSL-kernel manually. [Read this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5650#issuecomment-765825503)

- Download the latest kernel from here: https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=wsl
- Open and extract the update to your desktop
- Load a command prompt with elevated privileges (Start --> cmd --> Right-click --> Run as Administrator)
- Run these commands in the command prompt:

```
cd C:\Users\your_username\Desktop\
wsl --shutdown
wsl_update_x64.msi
wsl
uname -r
```

This should update the kernel and show you the latest running version.

Comment: I tried this but it installs it in the admin account and not for my user, if I run the msi without administrator permissions doesn't update anything

Comment: Wokred for me, thanks for providing these instructions!

Comment: Quite old releases

Comment: @karadayi Seems this catalog is abandoned: on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL2-Linux-Kernel) they list 5.15.146.1 as latest but you can also find 6.1.21.2 there

Comment: 5.15 is not listed